# Stop-AzureWebsiteJob results in "Not Found"

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

so I've set up a build/deployment in VSO where I want to stop the website and web jobs before deployment (because otherwise files are locked). The powershell script essentially contains:

Stop-AzureWebsite -Name $website # this works, website is stopped after

$jobs = Get-AzureWebsiteJob -Name $website # this works, contains a list of the jobs

Stop-AzureWebsiteJob -Name $website -JobName $job -PassThru

This last line fails, using the names returned from the preceding call I get an unhelpful "Not Found".  It's not an account / subscription thing as the preceding lines work happily, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is Remove-AzureWebsiteJob.

Regarding Stop-AzureWebsiteJob command, Starting and stopping Web Jobs is an operation that is only valid on continuous Web Jobs.

Based on the debug log (add -Debug to the command), it is trying to stop a continuous job https://[sitename].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/jobs/**continuous**/[jobname]/stop.

Regarding your requirement, you can try to stop the job through [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API).

There is the sample for using Azure App Service Kudu REST API that you can refer to:
[Samples for using the Azure App Service Kudu REST API to programmatically manage files in your site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gabeshapiro/2017/01/01/samples-for-using-the-azure-app-service-kudu-rest-api-to-programmatically-manage-files-in-your-site/)

Related thread: [Azure Stop a Triggered Web Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636995/azure-stop-a-triggered-web-job)

Comment: Thanks, I used that, combined with Remove-AzureWebsiteJob solved my problem (which was file locks screwing up a deployment).  Much abliged

Comment: Cool, this is the ticket, also *obliged ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple command:

```
Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <RG-NAME> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/continuouswebjobs -ResourceName <APP-SERVICE/WebJobName> -Action stop -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
```