# Cancel single WebJob execution

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

I have the current situation. Some big processes are made on Azure Web Jobs, and we have a lot of customers, each one of those customers can execute an instance of those functions triggered by Azure Queue. I have a button on our website (Azure App Service) that says "cancel execution", how can I cancel the execution of that Azure Web Job for that customer after clicking the button?

I was thinking of creating a cancellation queue that triggers that WebJob and has some logic to cancel the other execution, is there some way of doing it? Should I use cancellation tokens?

```
public static void EngineForProcessQueue([QueueTrigger(WebJobHelper.JOB_FOR_PROCESS_QUEUE)] string message, TextWriter log)
{
      ProcessQueueMessage(message, log);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [srgrn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989659/srgrn), In your website clicking the button to stop web job. you need to specify the ***process id***/***job name***.

You can use the [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Process-Threads-list-and-minidump-gcdump-diagsession) and `powershell` script to kill the web job process

```
  $username = $website.PublishingUsername
    $password = $website.PublishingPassword
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
    $ps = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/processes" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET    
    $id = $($ps | where {$_.name -eq $jobname} ).id
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/processes/$id" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method DELETE    
    write-host "killed process $id"
```

Refer [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29485249/15997690)